# Combine For /F with WMIC + WHERE clause + AND clause

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, syntax, wmic

How should this WMIC command be written when included in a `FOR` command in a script?

```
wmic service where (name="themes" and state="running") get
```

The code below does not work:

```
For /F %%a in (
    'wmic service where ^("name='themes'" and "state='running'"^) get'
) do (
    echo %%a
)
```

Comment: single quotes indicates end of parsed command...??

Comment: `=` is delimiter and should be escaped

Comment: Thanks a lot @npocmaka but I've tried it, does not work

Comment: I've never seen before how is the syntax treatment of a `For` with a wmic using an `AND` clausule, this is interesting for me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@echo off
For /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`wmic service where 'name^="themes" and state^="running"' get`) do (
    echo %%a
)
```

this one works for me.I've used `usebackq` option to have no problems with `'` and alternative wmic syntax  - `'` instead of brackets.

Answer (score 12):

Yet another option :)

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic service where "name='themes' and state='running'" get'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do echo %%B
```

Complex WHERE clauses must be either quoted, or parenthesized. Extra internal `'` do not cause problems with FOR /F.

I added an extra FOR /F to strip out the unwanted carriage return that is appended to the end of each line as an artifact of FOR /F converting the WMIC unicode output to ANSII. Without the extra FOR /F, there is an extra line consisting solely of a carriage return that results in `ECHO is off.` at the end.

I think I prefer jeb's version because it eliminates need for escape throughout the entire command, although I would probably use single quotes within the WHERE clause. For example:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  '"wmic service where (name='themes' and state='running') get name, pathName"'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do echo %%B
```

Using the syntax in my first code example requires escaping the commas in the GET clause:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%A in (
  'wmic service where "name='themes' and state='running'" get name^, pathName'
) do for /f "delims=" %%B in ("%%A") do echo %%B
```

Answer (score 11):

You can enclose the complete wmic command in single+double quotes, then you don't need to escape anything

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ('"wmic service where (name="themes" and state="running") get"') do (
  echo %%a
)
```

Comment: Yes both solutions are great, I just marked the answer of the person who answered first, but thankyou to both guys!